# How can I share my virtual machine to others?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation

I am working with an Ubuntu 18.04 virtual machine. I can SSH into this machine via puTTy on the same computer. However, how can I access this machine from another computer? Or do I have any option to set this machine as a cloud server so others can access and run it?

Comment: This is way off topic, it's too broad, nothing to do with coding and can easily be googled. Just adjust the firewall and SSH in.

Answer (score 0):

I think that would all depend on how the networking is configured on your VM.

You can configure the network as bridged (where the VM has it's own dedicated IP address on the local subnet), NAT (where the VM shares the IP with the system running Workstation, but NAT rules can be configured to handle traffic), or host-only (where only the system running Workstation is able to connect to it).

Bridged is probably the easiest to use for your situation.

More information on these networking configs: [Common Networking Configurations for Workstation](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/15.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-D9B0A52D-38A2-45D7-A9EB-987ACE77F93C.html)